# Android WebView Not Loading HTML

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to load HTML I received from Webservice but it's not rendered in webview here is my Code

```
WebView webView = (WebView) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.app_banner_html, null);
                webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                webView.loadData("htmlContent","text/html","UTF-8");
```

HTML content

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ishTmu9HXtDRdEN_bVOIZEe5J8gpl9fp6B3yr-sThvo/edit?usp=sharing

XML

```
 <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/web"/>
```

Comment: What is in that HTML content..!!! It has more than 300 pages of code in it.

Comment: 3 minutes and its still hasn't load completely on my pc dude. It has a long long code of base64 string in it.

Comment: yes I am passing HTML as string that I have received from my web service

Comment: But that html string has a long base64 string in it. Why?

Comment: every URL in HTML is in base64

Comment: I am not sure why you would do that but instead of putting images as base64 use a `url` for them. Your html code has 300 pages of base64 string and it was still going on until I gave up.